# ansible playbook - vars_files - "undefined variable" error

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use a vars file within a playbook - in this case to set a machine's hostname.

```
$ cat data_machine_test.yml 
---
host_name: test02


$ cat os-build_hostname_set.yml 
---
- name:  Set hostname
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - data_machine_test.yml

  tasks:

  - name: Set hostname
    hostname:
      name: "{{ host_name }}"
```

The variable file appears to be being read ...

```
PLAY [Set hostname] ************************************************************
META: ran handlers
Read vars_file 'data_machine_test.yml'
```

... but I keep getting the error ...

> ```
> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'host_name' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_6__unix/os-build_hostname_set.yml': line 10, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Set hostname\n    ^ here\n",
>     "_ansible_no_log": false
> ```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. You might want to double check the path(s) settings in AWX.

Comment: Thanks.  It turned out not to be an issue with the playbooks.   The issue was that the Git repository was not updating with the latest versions of the playbooks.

Comment: You might want to delete both your answer and question.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
$ cat data_machine_test.yml 
---
host_name: test02


$ cat os-build_hostname_set.yml 
---
- name:  Set hostname
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - data_machine_test.yml

  tasks:

  - name: Set hostname
    hostname:
      name: "{{ host_name }}"
```

Output:

It appears that the variables file is being read ...

```
PLAY [Set hostname] ************************************************************
META: ran handlers
Read vars_file 'data_machine_test.yml'
```

... but I keep getting the error ...

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'host_name' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_6__unix/os-build_hostname_set.yml': line 10, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Set hostname\n    ^ here\n",
    "_ansible_no_log": false
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not an answer. It's not a problem to answer your own question but... with an actual answer. In this case, you should edit your question and add the additional information to your original post.